# Sending data back to electron desktop app from external browser

Tags: node.js, electron

how do i receive data back to my electron app from the url opened in external browser.
basically i am trying to get streamlabs auth token for which i am opening up external browser for the user to authenticate with streamlabs auth and when the streamlabs api sends the data back to redirect url i want to get that data back to my electron app.

to open in external browser i am using

```
app.controller('setupCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.openurl = function(url) {
        var shell = require('electron').shell;      
        shell.openExternal(url);
    }    
});
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="st-api-key">  <!-- here the data from browser will go-->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click='openurl("http://localhost:8080")'> here</button>
```

http://localhost:8080 is my web service which is running in different app below

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
const axios = require('axios')
const STREAMLABS_API_BASE = 'https://www.streamlabs.com/api/v1.0'

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        let authorize_url = `${STREAMLABS_API_BASE}/authorize?`
        let params = {
          'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
          'redirect_uri': process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
          'response_type': 'code',
          'scope': 'donations.read+donations.create',
          }

        authorize_url += Object.keys(params).map(k => `${k}=${params[k]}`).join('&')
        res.redirect(`${authorize_url}`);
})

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  let code = req.query.code
  axios.post(`${STREAMLABS_API_BASE}/token?`, {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    'redirect_uri': process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
    'code': code
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.access_token)
    var token = response.data.access_token

      console.log(token) //*****this token need to be sent to electron app**********

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: I don't understand, why you open an external browser. You could open a new electron browserwindor for your streamlabs, authenticate, then you have the token in the cookies and you can grab it from there on the main process.

Comment: ya can do that but generally people have there accounts logged-in in their os default browsers so it could be much easy as a user point of view they don't have to login.and its more of a hobby project so experimenting around with new things

Comment: and also i don't want to bind my streamlabs app client id and secrets to clients application could be unsecure

Comment: That was not the idea - I thought that you open a browser window so that they authenticate with THEIR own accounts (username, password, whatever). After that, you have the token in the cookies within the electron app.

Comment: dont know if this is a good idea...create a server in your electron app and get the data with an api?

Comment: how does discord do the same with their authentication any idea sir?